# Cartesian Chart add line series in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have an Ext.net Cartesian chart, and I would like to add the dynamic line series in code behind with ASP.net C# with code below.

```
LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
lineSeries.XField = "Date1";
lineSeries.YField     = new string[1] { PayType };
lineSeries.Fill       = false;
CartesianChart2.Series.Add(lineSeries);
```

But my Cartesian chart doesn't show the line series I add in code behind..

If I hardcode code below to my .aspx, it can show the line and so the data.
I have tried CartesianChart.Update () or CartesianChart.Render (), neither work for me ..

```
<ext:LineSeries XField="Date1" YField="apple" Fill="false">
    <Listeners>
        <ItemMouseUp Handler="Ext.net.Notification.show({title:'Item Selected', html:item.value[1] + ' visits on ' + Ext.Date.monthNames[item.value[0]]});" />
    </Listeners>

    <Tooltip runat="server" TrackMouse="true">
        <Renderer Handler="this.setTitle(storeItem.get('Date1') + '<br />' + storeItem.get('apple')); this.update(storeItem.get('apple'));"></Renderer>
    </Tooltip>

    <StyleSpec>
        <ext:Sprite LineWidth="3" />
    </StyleSpec>

    <Marker>
        <ext:CircleSprite Radius="4" LineWidth="0" />
    </Marker>
</ext:LineSeries>
```

I have no idea why.